# How to display only specific data from a XML file in PHP with an array with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, filtering, text-extraction, atom-feed

I've found an Atom feed where all currency rates towards Euro are displayed.
I'm totally new to XML files, and that's why I'm asking how could I only display several rates (defined in an array) and not all the rates in a PHP file?

Here is my PHP code (with the link to the source XML file):

```
<?php
$fichier = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Av2v4lMxiJ1AdE9laEZJdzhmMzdmcW90VWNfUTYtM2c/1/public/basic';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichier);

$cur_arr = array('AED','CAD','USD');

foreach($xml as $entry){
    echo $entry->title.' '; 
    echo substr($entry->content, 8, 8).'<br /><br>';    
}
?>
```

I would like to display only the rates of the currencies specified in my array (AED, CAD, USD).

Comment: Thank you for including your coding attempt. Please offer us some realistic sample data (directly in the question) and your exact desired output.

Comment: Yes, agree strongly with @mickmackusa - most important is to include an example of your xml file, accessing specific elements of that data is quite straightforward using teh SimpleXML library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, only needed to apply `in_array()` and adjust the substr() parameters (unless you were deliberately truncating the decimal length).

Tested Code:

```
$fichier = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Av2v4lMxiJ1AdE9laEZJdzhmMzdmcW90VWNfUTYtM2c/1/public/basic';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichier);

$cur_arr = array('AED','CAD','USD');

foreach($xml as $entry){
    if (in_array($entry->title, $cur_arr)) {
        echo "<div>$entry->title : " , substr($entry->content, 8) , "</div>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AED : 4.196204158
CAD : 1.500774188
USD : 1.142446
```

If you want all of the numbers to be "padded" with zeros to a certain number of decimal places, use `str_pad()`.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your help ! That's exactly what I was looking for ! Next time I'll include some sample data.